# How to speed up the GPT4 API

Tags: openai-api, dbeaver, chat-gpt-4

I'm using the GPT4 API in your web service.

When a user asks a question in natural language, it is converted to SQL.

I'm using the prompt below.

```
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model='gpt-4',
    temperature=0.1,
    message=[{"role": "system",
                 "content": '''
                     -- Metadata: Metadata is as follows.{}
                     -- Response Format: Answer only in the format "Explain: explanation, Query: SQL query". 
                     -- Example: 
                        Explain: This query is ... 
                        Query: 
                        SELECT ...
                        FROM ...
                     -- After "Query:", You must write only SQL query.
                     -- Provide the reason and explanation in the same language as the question.
                     '''.format(metadata)},
                {"role": "user", "content": "{}".format(message)}]
)
```

But it's too slow. It takes an average of 20 seconds to get a response.

However, it takes about 3 seconds to convert natural language to sql in DBeaver AI (GPT) integration.

How can I speed up my response time?

Comment: It's not really possible to speed up chatgpt4 api because you don't controll it..
However you can use gpt 3.5 turbo to get better speed generation text or use another ia.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API: How do I make the API return a completion faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76962144/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-api-how-do-i-make-the-api-return-a-completion-faster)

Answer (score 0):

###### 1. **Use Faster Models**:

gpt-3.5-turbo is often much faster than GPT-4.

You may also want to
consider other models like Llama2, which are available with various
API providers.

This might lead to a
decrease in the quality of results, so I recommend implementing SQL
validation to mitigate this issue.

Additionally, you can use LLM API adapters like
[ai-microcore](https://github.com/Nayjest/ai-microcore) to avoid
dependency on a specific LLM & experiment with different models & API providers.

###### 2. **Use Streaming**

If you are displaying the results of generation directly to the user without any post-processing, consider using streaming.

This can significantly enhance the user experience as it dramatically improves perceived performance.